# Why is this matrix product diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Someone can help me with this following problem?

> Let $A,B$ be symmetric matrices. If $A$ is positive definite, then
>   $AB$ is diagonalizable.

Thanks!

P.S. The matrices are over $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive-definite, there exists an invertible square root of the matrix which is also symmetric. Denote this as $A^\frac{1}{2}$. Then
$$A^{-\frac{1}{2}}ABA^\frac{1}{2} = A^\frac{1}{2}BA^\frac{1}{2}$$
where the latter is symmetric because $B$ and $A^\frac{1}{2}$ are both symmetric. Therefore $AB$ is similar to a symmetric matrix and hence diagonalizable.

Comment: +1 for teaching a new trick, that if $X,Y$ are symmetric, so is $XYX$.

Comment: With a similar argument, $AB$ and $BA$ are both diagonalisable under the OP's assumptions.