# Is the product of a positive definite matrix with it's inverse diagonal diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

For some implementation of Hamiltonian dynamics I'd like to diagonalize a specific matrix $F$. $F$ can be constructed in multiple ways. I have a positive definite matrix $A$. It is real and symmetric and therefore Hermitian, and diagonalizable.

Now for $F$ I have three options:

- $F = I A = A$
- $F = A^{-1} A = I$
- $F = (\text{maindiagonal}(A)\; )^{-1} A $.

The first two are always diagonalizable. From my implementation, it seems that the third option is no different, but providing a proof for this is a little harder. Is there a way to prove the diagonalizeability?

Comment: I have deleted my previous post as it was stupid.One more question : do you consider diagonalisability over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: It should be diagonalizable over R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $F$ is diagonalizable with $>0$ eigenvalues because it's the product of $2$ positive symmetric matrices.

Comment: Proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317334/why-is-this-matrix-product-diagonalizable

Comment: The proof would have been nice in the original answer, but it checks out.