# Showing $u^T M u \geq v^TMv$ when $M$ is symmetric PD and $u,v$ are $0-1$ vectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix. Let $u$ and $v$ be vectors of length $n$ with entries consisting $n-m_u$ (or $n-m_v$) $0$'s and $m_u $ (or $m_v$) $1$'s, where $m_u,m_v \in \{1,...,n-1\}$. Sort $u$ so that the first $n-m_u$ entires of $u$ are $0$'s and the last $m_u$ entries are $1$'s. Sort $v$ in the same way. Suppose $m_u>m_v$. Is the following weak inequality true?

**(As shown below by @Niki Di Giano, this is not true)**
$$ u^T M u \geq v^TMv $$

Comment: I don't think you need all that, I think it is true in general for all the matrices with positive entries

Comment: @LucioTanzini That is absolutely true. Sorry, for the actual question, $X$ does not need to have only positive entries. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $M$:
$$M =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 10 & - 9\\
0 & -9 & 10\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Yields $u^T M u = 2$ and $v^T M v = 10$ for the vectors $u = (0, 1, 1)$ and $v =(0, 0, 1)$ respectively.

Comment: It is required that the number of $1$'s are strictly below $n$. Is it possible to show a counterexample for that case? Thank you.

Comment: @kenex I have edited the answer. As you can see it doesn't really matter since it easily generalises.

Answer (score 1):

Consider : $$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 2 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}, u  = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} ^T,   v  = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} ^T                       
$$

M is positive definite and : 
$$ u^T M u = v^T M v = 2 $$
so it's not a strict inequality (is $m_u \lt n$ ?). I couldn't find an example where the inequality is not working though.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Indeed, $m_n, m_v <n$. Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question.

Comment: I just checked and if you set $m_u =2$ and $m_v = 1$ you also get 2 so it’s still not working for $m_u \lt n$.

Comment: I see. I will edit the question to a weak inequality which I am still interested in showing. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but would you please help me on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318386/showing-det-big-bk-1-ak-big-o1-when-a-b-are-rank-1-updates)?

Comment: I saw Niki Di Giano’s answer and he proved that the inequality is false. What is left to prove?

Comment: What I hope to show is $$\frac{1+m_v}{1+m_u} 
\leq
\frac{1+u^\top(M+I_n)^{-1} u}{1+v^\top(M+I_n)^{-1} v}
\leq 
\frac{1+m_u}{1+m_v}$$ where  $m_v<m_u$, and $M$ is symmetric PD with positive entries.

Answer (score 1):

Another example where the inequality fails:

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3&-2\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite. Also, $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}>\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. But $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3&-2\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=2<3=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3&-2\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ which violates the inequality.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but would you please help me on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318386/showing-det-big-bk-1-ak-big-o1-when-a-b-are-rank-1-updates)?