# Showing $ u^T (M+I_n)^{-1} u \geq v^T(M+I_n)^{-1}v $ when $M$ is symmetric PD with positive entries and $u,v$ are $0-1$ vectors

Tags: matrices, inverse, quadratic-forms

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $m_u,m_v \in \{1,...,n-1 \}$.

Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix with positive entries.

Let $u$ and $v$ be vectors of length $n$ with entries consisting $n-m_u$ (or $n-m_v$) $0$'s and $m_u $ (or $m_v$) $1$'s. Sort $u$ so that the first $n-m_u$ entires of $u$ are $0$'s and the last $m_u$ entries are $1$'s. Sort $v$ in the same way.

Suppose $m_u>m_v$. Is the following weak inequality true?

**(As shown below by @Niki Di Giano, this is not true)**

$$ u^T (M+I_n)^{-1} u \geq v^T(M+I_n)^{-1}v $$

This is related to the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321518/showing-ut-x-u-vtxv-when-x-is-symmetric-pd-and-u-v-are-0-1-vectors) but now $M$ has positive entries only and we replace $M$ with $(M+I_n)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using almost the same matrix as the other post (if the matrix admits zero entries):
$$M =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 10 & 9\\
0 & 9 & 10\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then its inverse with the added identity is:
$$(M + I)^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 11/40 & -9/40\\
0 & -9/40 & 11/40\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This gives $u^T M u = 4/40$ and $v^T M v = 11/40$ for the vectors $u = (0, 1, 1)$ and $v =(0, 0, 1)$ respectively.

Alternatively, the matrix:

$$M =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 100 & 99\\
1 & 99 & 100\\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\implies (M + I)^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
100/199 & -1/398 & -1/398\\
-1/398 & 201/796 & - 197/796\\
-1/398 & - 197/796 & 201/796\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which gives $8/796$ and $201/796$ for the same two vectors.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am wondering if I can bound $\frac{1+u^T(M+I)^{-1} u}{1+v^T(M+I)^{-1} v}$ by $\frac{1+m_v}{1+m_u}$ and  $\frac{1+m_u}{1+m_v}$. The question is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322207/frac1m-v1m-u-leq-frac1utmi-1-u1vtmi-1v-leq-frac1). Sorry to bother you again, but would you plz help me on this?

Comment: The motivating question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318386/finding-bounds-for-det-big-bk-1-ak-big-in-terms-of-det-b-1).